# If statement on update statement Instead of trigger?

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure where I will calculate factors by merging some tables and updates in table 'tablea'. I have created a trigger on `tablea` so when there is a update those records will entered into new table 'tablea_new'. My problem with trigger is I will have 6 months factors updated at a time but they some months factors may not updated but they should entered in to new table.So trigger troubled me a lot.

So I went with an `If` statement to insert update records

My code for `If` statement is

```
@Action A
SET A.Factor=B.Net/B.Cost,A.Net=B.Net,A.LastModified=sysDatetime(),A.LastModifiedBy=suser_name(),A.Path=B.Path
FROM Tablea A
INNER JOIN ##TEMP3 B ON
A.Year=B.Year AND
A.Month=B.Month AND
A.Media=B.Media
 IF @Action='UPDATE'
   BEGIN


   INSERT INTO Tablea_New (ID,Media,Year,Month,Factor,Net,UpdatedDate,UpdatedBy,FilePath)
SELECT ID,Media,Year,Month,Factor,Net,LastModified,LastModifiedBy,FilePath FROM Tablea
WHERE Media='CNN'AND YEAR=@YEAR AND Net >1
END
```

Can you guys give me some suggestions is there can I make some modifications or I need to use triggers :(

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Change Data Capture (CDC) feature in SQL Server 2008 R2. This will help you to automatically store all changed rows, irrespective of the type of change (i.e. whether it is insert, update or delete).

To enable CDC for your database, use the below script

```
USE your_database_name
GO 
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
```

To enable CDC for your table, use the below script

```
EXEC SYS.sp_cdc_enable_table 
@source_schema = N'your_schema_name',
@source_name = N'your_table_name',
@role_name = NULL
```

Once CDC is enabled, a new table is created under schema 'cdc' to store the changed rows, along with metadata about the change. You may directly access this table to get the required data.